# What are problems an $M$ - estimator is trying to solve?

Tags: statistics, robust-statistics

Anyone here have any experience with $M$ - estimators and do you think you can give a brief explanation that the problem an $M$ - estimator is trying to solve ? 
Thanks.

Comment: While your question is interesting, this site is not really geared toward expository essays on broad topics. If you'd like a useful reference, I recommend A. van der Vaart, *[Asymptotic Statistics](http://www.amazon.com/Asymptotic-Statistics-Statistical-Probabilistic-Mathematics/dp/0521784506)*, Cambridge University Press, 1998, **Chapter 5**.

Answer (score 0):

I, particularly, have encountered with the following ones:

1) Loss-minimization problem in Machine Learning.

2) Maximum Likelihood estimation.